# In an electric circuit in a magnetic field, Would we consider the induced emf produced by changing of magnetic field in calculating potential diff?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Change in magnetic field creates a non conservative Electric field and while potential difference is used in conservative field only so...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Consider that the emf from a generator is produced by a changing magnet flux.

Comment: Thanks, got it!! :)